# 2x2 Matrix Question how to show $A(-\theta)$

Tags: matrices, trigonometry

The question is as follows -
If $A(\theta)= $$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$ $
show that $A^{-1}(\theta)=A(-\theta)$

I've already worked out that $A^{-1}(\theta)=$$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$
So ofcourse $A(-\theta)$ is equal to same as above but I don't know how to mathematically show it

Comment: You're done. What does it mean to you to *show something mathematically*?

Comment: Okay so I mean, how would I show $A(\theta)$ = $A(-\theta)$, as in I don't know what $A(-\theta)$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note thta $\sin(-\theta)=-\sin\theta$ and $\cos(-\theta)=\cos\theta$

$$A(\theta)A(-\theta)=\begin{bmatrix}  \cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta&\cos\theta \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos(-\theta) &-\sin(-\theta) \\ \sin(-\theta) & \cos(-\theta) \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta &\cos\theta\sin\theta-\cos\theta\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta\cos\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta & \sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Therefore, $A^{-1}(\theta)=A(-\theta)$

It is another method to prove $A^{-1}(\theta)=A(-\theta)$.

Comment: Is $A^{-1}(\theta)$ the same as $A(\theta)^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes :) I prefer to use that. But I will edit it

Comment: I don't understand your final matrix of 1s and 0s how would that be seen as being the same as ${A^-1}(\theta)$

Comment: Because $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta =1$ and $\cos\theta\sin\theta-\cos\theta\sin\theta=0$ :)

Comment: Ah!  the definition of inverse matrix of a matrix $A$ is a matrix $B(=A^{-1})$ such that $AB=0$. Thus, $A(-\theta)=A^{-1}(\theta)$

Comment: No I understand that but what I'm not sure about is how would you see they are the same when $A^{-1}(\theta)$ consists of cos and sin while $A(-\theta)$ does not consist of sin and cos surely they'd both need to be in the same format to see that one is same as the other? So how would your final matrix look with cos and sin?

Comment: Oh! sorry I made a mistake, if $B $ is the inverse matrix of $A$, $$AB=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0 // 0&1   \end{bmatrix}$$.

And $A(-\theta)$ does consist of sin and cos as the first line of the equation

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not able to understand this method I just can't see this $$ \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1 \end{bmatrix} $$ as being same as this \begin{bmatrix}  \cos\theta&\sin\theta\\ -\sin\theta&\cos\theta \end{bmatrix}

Comment: They are not same....  Actually, you already have proved it from your question. Can you see that 
$$A(-\theta)=\begin{bmatrix}  \cos(-\theta) & -\sin(-\theta)\\ \sin(-\theta) &\cos(-\theta)  \end{bmatrix}$$?

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a rotation matrix (used pretty heavily in applications), sometimes also known as the Givens rotation (named after Wallace Givens). 
The inverse of a rotation matrix is its transpose, which is also a rotation matrix.

For a rotation matrix $A$,

\begin{equation*}
\left(A^{T}\right)^{T} A^{T} = A A^{T} =\mathbb{I}
\end{equation*}

Here the transpose is also reflection (hence $A(-\theta)=\left(A(\theta)\right)^{T}$) By the way, this can be generalized to any dimension. This (Givens rotation concept) is sometimes used in QR decomposition as an efficient implementation algorithm.

Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation

Comment: Okay so when I multiply the original matrix by its transposed I get this matrix \begin{bmatrix} \cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta &\ 0 \\ \ 0 & \sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta \end{bmatrix} but how does mean that $A^{-1}(\theta)=A(-\theta)$ because $A^{-1}(\theta)$ does not look like this?

Comment: Do you notice that, this is identity matrix? (because $\sin^{2}(\theta)+\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)=1$). Do you also notice that $A(-\theta)=A^{T}\left(\theta\right)$?. Basically, $A(\theta)A^{T}(\theta)=A(\theta)A(-\theta)=\mathbb{I}=A(\theta)A^{-1}(\theta)$. Now, do you see the picture?

Comment: So you're saying that essentially $A(-\theta)=A^{T}$ & if I put that next to the inverse matrix they look the same?

Comment: Yes, reflection, transpose and inverse are all the same, for this matrix.